# CLR Sync Block Address

Tags: c#, heap-memory, clr

When I do:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int exp;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Employee o1 = new Employee();
        o1.exp = 3;
        lock (o1)
        {
            //I am here
        }
    }
}
```

and get memory of o1 (address is 0x022cf940):

[image]

I realized couple of things mentioned below:

1. Green rectangle is sync block, which is 12
2. Blue rectangle is 4 byte address of type
3. Red rectangle is 4 byte integer, which is 3;

Question: Where is the space of sync blocks and how can I find it? 
What does "12" stand for?

Comment: Your image indicates this is a 32-bit system. The green rectangle is your Syncblk with value 12 (and the flag BIT_SBLK_IS_HASH_OR_SYNCBLKINDEX = 0x08000000), the blue is your TypeHandle, the red is the value of your exp-field. Are you asking us where the Syncblk Entry Table can be found? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S7

Comment: Perhaps the syncblk.h code could be of help? https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/syncblk.h

Comment: The value (0x12) is an index into a movable table. The location of that table is a concern to the CLR only, there should be no need for a programmer to know. And hence no API to find out.

Comment: Henk Holterman - as Hans Passant says, is System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The sync block has more than one use.  It can store the value of Object.GetHashCode() so that an object always returns the same hash code when GetHashCode() is called again.  It can store the ID of the owner thread of a *lock* statement.  It has several dedicated bits, like indicating that the finalizer for an object has been run.  And it can store a handle to an allocated sync block, necessary when a thread both called GetHashCode *and* used lock and the info can't fit in the sync block anymore.  It is very heavily micro-optimized.

Your case is the simple case, only *lock* was called and none of the dedicated bits are turned on.  So you see the owner of the lock, 0x12 = 18 is the Thread.ManagedThreadId of the thread that owns the lock.  That can come in pretty doggone handy when you ever need to troubleshoot a deadlock.

You can make the debugger display a bit easier to interpret when you right-click the window and select "4-byte Integer".  The blue rectangle is the method table pointer for the object (aka "type handle").  It indicates the type of the object, Object.GetType() uses it.  The red rectangle is where the object starts storing its fields.  Since yours only has the `exp` field and its type is Int32, you can see 3 back.

Comment: So, is System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId. Thanks!

Comment: @Hans, if the syncblock is 4 bytes (or 8 bytes), then it can hold one of the hashcode, the lock owner thread Id, a handle to an allocated sync block, etc. But don't these things require *all* the space in the syncblock? So where is the bit or bits that indicate which one of these things is held? And where do the bits for GC etc reside.

Comment: Yes, those are the "dedicated bits" I talked about.  Object.GetHashCode() doesn't use a 32 bit hash code, it uses 26 bits.  Not a problem, you never create 4 billion objects.  Click the Ask Question button if you want to know more.

Comment: The value in this case represents an index entry within SyncBlock table where you have to lookup lock owner. What you describe is when `BIT_SBLK_IS_HASH_OR_SYNCBLKINDEX = 0x08000000` is cleared (ThinLock). The https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e3ff5770757ee1696b18c927d5fea1b44d003459/src/vm/syncblk.h#L115 says: > if `BIT_SBLK_IS_HASH_OR_SYNCBLKINDEX` **is clear**, the rest of the header dword is layed out as follows: lower ten bits (bits 0 thru 9) is **thread id** used for the **thin lock**... if BIT_SBLK_IS_HASH_OR_SYNCBLKINDEX is set...the rest of the dword is the sync block **index**

Comment: That is not correct.  A sync block is only used if the object was used as a lock *and* GetHashCode() was called.  Which in properly designed code should be never.

Comment: @HansPassant, i'm just looking at the green line and read it as "0x08000021", am I reading that right? And there is that 0x08000000 bit set. Because when I look at value 3, it's written "backwards". So I thought I have to read syncblock field like that too, or not?

Comment: This is of course not the proper way to ask for assistance.  Click the "Ask Question" button, show repro steps and version numbers.

Comment: Hans I dont argue about what you said. I argue what I see in provided screenshot. What you say is generally true. But i'm skeptical if 12 is thread id in this particular case. Thats all.