# Can define thread safe object as Readonly variable?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Can I define lockObject like bellow:

```
private readonly object lockObject;
```

Or should be defile like this:

```
private object lockObject;
```

Comment: If you should never need to write to a field after initialization, then define it as read-only. A lock object would be a good example of something that should not be changing.

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot Thanks, But Do .net framework need to write to lock object?

Comment: But you need to *create* the object. Normally you would write: `private readonly object lockObject = new object();`

Comment: @Fred No. The `lock` instruction (and in general the `Monitor.Enter`/`Monitor.Exit` that "implement" the `lock`) use some metadata in a special table that is connected to the `object`

Comment: @Fred - *Nothing* should ever change the lock object, as that would make the entire concept useless.

Comment: @xanatos Thanks,I initialize it in class constructor.

Comment: Using *readonly* is formally correct.  Whether it ever catches a programmer getting locking so drastically wrong is doubtful.

Comment: Here it explains that in Microsoft .NET the `lock` writes in some "hidden" memory prepended to the locked object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690790/clr-sync-block-address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**99.99% of the time use readonly**

Traditionally you would want a readonly object as your lock, the reason being is that the lock is being done on the object at the variable `lockObject` if you don't make it readonly and it changes there could be a case where the lock is being placed on a different object for multiple threads.

Heres a nice list explanation of a senario that could cause issues without using a readonly lock

1. Thread A grabs lock at `lockObject`
2. Thread B changes variable at `lockObject`
3. Thread C grabs lock at `lockObject`, which is different than the lock in step 1

**For the 0.01% of the time**

This would be when you want to change your lock for some reason, i.e. the resource that you are controlling access to changed but there are possibly still threads working on the previous resource and you consider their current operations still valid for your program, and you don't want to wait for them to change the lock out. **Again this comes with the warning, you probably should not do this**.