# Why CLR object reference contains address to the middle of an object?

Tags: .net, clr

Objects in CLRv4 are laid out in memory in such a way:

- sync block
- pointer to method table
- user-defined fields

Object references are implemented in a way that seems odd to me - reference is actually a pointer to field containing pointer to method table. In other words it contains shifted address of an object (it does not point to the beginning of the object but just after sync block). Source: [CLR Sync Block Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690790/clr-sync-block-address)

Why it has been implemented in such a way? I believe it might be related to performance - method table is probably more likely to be accessed than sync block and in such case less operations are required. However, if that's the case then it would be more natural to reorder sync block and pointer to method table so the latter is at the beginning of an object. What are the reasons for such layout?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/syncblk.h#L21

Comment: It was micro-optimized to make the machine code that accesses a boxed value type value as compact as possible.  Allowing it to be generated inline without a call to a CLR helper function.  Also explains the seemingly odd restriction in C# that you must always unbox to a value of the exact same type.  Mattered a great deal in .NET 1.x, not today with generics available.